# Weird behaviour. Functions outside of class change it's instance variables

Tags: python, scope

I don't know if I'm missing something extremely obvious, but i found this behaviour to be surprising.

EDIT:
Ok so here is an example where i do not use any default arguments - unlike linked duplicate - and it still behaves that way. Can someone please explain why?

```
class Manager(object):
    @classmethod
    def calculatesomething(cls, array, attr):
        array.append(attr)
        return 1

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        variable = Manager.calculatesomething(self.array, attr)
        return variable


a = MyClass(['one', 'two', 'three'])
print a.array
print a.four
print a.array
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
1
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

What i expected:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
1
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Just like when we have a simple function:

```
def f(a):
    a += 1
    return a
a = 1

print a
print f(a)
print a
```

I expect:

```
1
2
1
```

and that's exactly what i get.

Comment: What exactly is surprising to you about this behaviour? What do you *expect* instead?

Comment: @deceze I find it surprising that method 'calculatesomething' can actually change array instance variable of MyClass(). I will add further information what i expected.

Comment: You are passing (a reference to) a `list` object and are mutating that object. There's no copy being created of `self.array` when you pass it into another function, you're passing *the one and only instance* of the object.

Comment: This has been treated in quite a few questions here, really.

Comment: `+=` reassigns a variable, it doesn't mutate the instance like `.append()` does.

Comment: @deceze except when the class redefines `__radd__` to mutate itself, cf `list.__radd__` which calls `self.extend` and returns `self` ;)

Comment: @bruno Let's keep it simple, shall we? ;)

Comment: @Kesto deceze is still right in that your "simple function" example rebinds a local name. Rewrite it using a list and mutating that list (well, using just any mutable object and mutating it) and you'll find out.

Comment: @deceze well if the op was to try it's "simple function" with a list and using `+=another_list` on it he would be ever more perplexed xD

Comment: So basically i have to create a new list, extend it by 'array' and then append 'attr' to it? It works perfectly fine this way, but i'd like to know if this is the correct way to work with this problem. This is kinda embarassing.